# thread_local and std::future object - what is the lifetime of an object?

Tags: c++, c++11, future, lifetime

Here's my test code:

```
vector<int> const & foo(int const counter)
{
    thread_local static vector<int> v{counter, counter + 1, counter + 2};
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    using myFut = future<vector<int> const &>;

    vector<myFut> futures;
    for(int i{0}; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        futures.push_back(async(launch::async, &foo, i * 3));
    }

    for(myFut & fut : futures)
    {
        vector<int> v{fut.get()}; // or vector<int> const & v{fut.get()};
        cout << v.size() << endl; // 0, I expect 3
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When `foo()` returns a thread can be destroyed - together with a `thread_local` variable. But since I'm using a `std::future` the lifetime of the variable should be prolonged until the call to `std::future::get()`, right? But in my case the `std::future` returns an empty vector. So what are the rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But since I'm using a std::future the lifetime of the variable should be prolonged until the call to std::future::get(), right?

That's not the case. The thread used by std::async will call `set_value()` on the `std::promise` associated with the future, and then it's free to terminate. Therefore, your thread-local variable may well be destroyed before `std::future::get()` returns or even before you call it.